# Get last value from Column A printed in Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I have random numbers in my Excel sheet, and in a particular cell I want the last value from Column A printed. What would be the formula for that?

Currently I have tried applying formulas like:

```
=IF(F:F<=240,(A2:A101<=240),0)
```

or

```
=IF(F:F<=240,MAX(A2:A101<=240),0)
```

without any result.

Comment: Could you please specify what result you want to get?

Comment: There are many values in column A which are less than 240, I want to return the last value which is less than 240

Comment: You can get the last value with: `=INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A))`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using the `ROW()` function in an array formula.

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$101,MAX(IF($A$2:$A$101<=240,ROW($A$2:$A$101)-ROW($A$2)+1,0)))
```

Enter the formula with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` to make it an **array formula**. `{}` will appear around it.

The `IF` part returns an array of item indexes, that match the criteria `<=240`, and 0 for rows that don't (`{1,0,3,4,0,6,...}` when items 1,3,4,6 match the criteria). The index in the range is calculated by `(row - first_row + 1)`. Then `MAX` returns the largest item index from the array, and `INDEX` return the item value from the range according to its index.

*I didn't understand how F is involved, but this method can be adjusted to accommodate it.